# Clique with one vertex

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm

Is there a clique possible in Graph with one vertex? I mean, is a singleton vertex in itself is a complete sub-graph and can be called a clique.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. We can have a clique of size 1 (the vertex itself) which comprises the entire graph and is connected to every other vertex (itself).

Comment: **Just wanted to expand my tiny horizons! Thank you! :)**